# How to DRY up directional logic from a try/except mess

Tags: python

I'm trying to simplify my solution to [Project Euler's problem 11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11) (find the greatest product of 4-in-a-row numbers in a 20x20 grid).

My main gripe with my answer are the four try/except clauses in the definition of sub_lists_at_xy. I have one for each direction (east, south, southeast, and southwest) of 4-in-a-row lists that could possibly run off the board. Do you have any suggestions for simplifying or DRYing up this implementation?

```
from operator import mul

with open("11.txt") as f:
    nums = [[int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] for line in f.read().split('\n')]

def prod(lst):
    return reduce(mul, lst, 1)

def sub_lists_at_xy(array, length, x, y):

    try:
        east=array[y][x:x+length]
    except IndexError:
        east=[0]*length

    try:
        south=[list[x] for list in array[y:y+length]] 
    except IndexError:
        south=[0]*length

    try:
        southeast=[array[y+i][x+i] for i in range(length)]
    except IndexError:
        southeast=[0]*length

    try:
        southwest=[array[y+i][x-i] for i in range(length)]
    except IndexError:
        southwest=[0]*length    

    return east, south, southeast, southwest

sub_lists=[]

for x in range(len(nums[0])):
    for y in range(len(nums)):
        sub_lists += sub_lists_at_xy(nums, 4, x, y)
best = max(prod(lst) for lst in sub_lists)
print(best)
```

Comment: Why don't you test that your x and y values are within bounds first, then you can avoid all of the `try...excepts`.

Comment: is there an elegant way to do this? It was my first inclination that each of east, south, southeast, and southwest would require different checks for x and/or y. And when I did some research I found that it was suggested to get in the habit of using `try...except`s to avoid race conditions (though this isn't a concern in this case).

Comment: @dylan - Where did you read this about race conditions and try/catch?  They aren't very closely related - exceptions won't prevent race conditions.

Comment: @dfb cant find it now but I was reading a discussion about the virtues of _look before you leap_ and _easier to ask forgiveness than permission_. You're right, I'm not sure I understand why EAFP would prevent a race condition. More importantly the whole race condition thing is irrelevant in this case, as there's no chance of that happening here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow the don't-repeat-yourself rule, you could pull out the direction logic:

```
def sub_lists_at_xy(array, length, x, y):
    directions = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (-1, 1)]
    sublists = []
    for dx, dy in directions:
        try:
            seq = [array[y+dy*i][x+dx*i] for i in range(length)]
            sublists.append(seq)
        except IndexError:
            pass
    return sublists
```

You might want to check that I didn't get the directions wrong -- I usually make sign errors all over the place -- but you get the idea.

[Note: this isn't how I myself would do it, but it's how I would simplify your code.]

Comment: I like where you're going with this. Thanks @DSM.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the input, but you could also pad your array

```
with open("11.txt") as f:
    nums = [["X"] + [int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] + ["X"] for line in f.read().split('\n')]
    nums = ["X"]*(len(nums[0])+2) + nums + ["X"]*(len(nums[0])+2)
```

You can then filter your data

```
reduce(mul, [x for x in lst if x != "X"], 1)
```

Comment: You can, but it's not very pythonic.

Comment: @JoelCornett - Why is padding the data not Pythonic?  IMO it's cleaner than putting in a bunch of if statements to replace the try/except

Comment: yeah i was thinking of padding my array, but couldn't find an elegant way to do so. Your solution is intriguing.

Comment: @JoelCornett perhaps there's a more "implicit"/elegant way of padding that would achieve the same end.

Comment: You know, I thought about it, and I concede that it's not necessarily "unpythonic", but I think a set of if statements is pretty explicit and makes it very obvious what you're doing, while the code you posted above is less clear. (The above code would require a comment along the lines of `#pad the array to prevent indexerrors`, while a series of `if` statements, iff written correctly, would speak for themselves).

Comment: @JoelCornett - :).  Fair point with the comments. This is the typical solution for ACM style programming contests as well.